# For a covariance matrix, what would be the properties associated with the eigenvectors space of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I want to know, since the covariance matrix is symmetric, positive, and semi-definite, then if I calculate its eigenvectors what would be the properties of the space constructed by those eigenvectors (corresponds to non-close-zero eigenvalues), is it orthogonal or anything else special?
Suppose this eigenvector matrix is called U, then what would be the properties with
U*transpose(U)？

Comment: One can always set things up such that the matrix of eigenvectors of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix is an orthogonal matrix, zero eigenvalues or not.

Comment: How to set things up? and what would be the U*transpose(U)

Comment: Most eigenroutines would generate an orthogonal matrix of eigenvectors. *Mathematica* and MATLAB (due to how LAPACK routines are set up) do. Remember that multiplying an orthogonal matrix with its transpose gives an identity matrix.

Comment: @J.M.: Do you know what the eigenvectors of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix mean if the matrix is not necessarily a covariance matrix?

Comment: @Mitch: I tend to think of those things geometrically, much like Qiaochu's answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9758/9763#9763)... or you had something else in mind?

Answer (score 2):

A symmetric matrix has orthogonal eigenvectors (irrespective of being positive definite - or zero eigenvalues). Hence, if we normalize the eigenvectors, U * transpose(U) = I

Comment: This assumes, of course, that orthogonal bases have been selected for any degenerate eigenspaces.  For instance, $(1,0)$ and $(\sqrt{1/2}, \sqrt{1/2})$ form a normalized eigenbasis for the 2 by 2 identity matrix but $U U^T \ne I$.

Comment: @whuber: You're right.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvectors correspond to the [principal components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_components_analysis) and the eigenvalues correspond to the [variance explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_variance) by the principal components.